# NSDateComponentsFormatter stringFromTimeInterval returns incorrect string for intervals shorter than 1 minute

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I'm using NSDateComponentsFormatter on iOS 8 and i've noticed a possible bug in the implementation of the `stringFromTimeInterval:` method, but I can't say it for sure.

This is how I have set up the formatter:

```
NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorDefault;
formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStylePositional;
```

Now when I pass anything less than 60 seconds to the `stringFromTimeInterval:` method, the formatter returns either `1` or `01`, which is obviously wrong, it should return something like `0:XX`.

What I have also noticed is that by changing the `unitsStyle` to anything but `NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStylePositional` the method returns a correct string!

Example:

With `unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStylePositional`:

```
(lldb) po [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:12]
= "1"
```

=> Should return "0:12"!!

With `unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleAbbreviated`:

```
(lldb) po [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:12]
= "12 s"
```

=> Correct!

This lets me think that it is a bug in Apple's implementation of the API, or am I missing something?

Comment: Check out my answer/work-around below...

Comment: I know it's not the solution, but you can just set the float string value from the timeInterval if it's lower than 60:         

if (self.timeInterval < 60) {
            stringFromInterval = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.0f",self.timeInterval];
        }

Have you considerered to ask in the Apple Developer Forums?

Answer (score 10):

This seems to still be an issue with iOS 8.3 and Xcode 6.3.
There is a way to work around it however, which, if not perfect, at least allows you to get proper formatting without having to deal with splitting time relevant components yourself.

Here is an example workaround in Swift (which you can test in a Playground)

```
let formatter = NSDateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .Positional
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .Pad
formatter.allowedUnits = .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond
```

Calling `let string = formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(4)` will print "00:04".

Calling `let string = formatter.stringFromTimeInterval(88)` will print "01:28".

Now you can play with the `allowedUnits` depending on whether you have more than 1 hour or 1 day. For example in a class which has a `formatter` property:

```
func updateTimeFormatterForTime(time: NSTimeInterval) {
   if time > 3600 && time < 24 * 3600 {
      self.formatter.allowedUnits = .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond
   } else if time > 24 * 3600 {
      self.formatter.allowedUnits = .CalendarUnitDay | .CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute | .CalendarUnitSecond
   }
}
```

Comment: .CalendarUnitMinute and .CalendarUnitHour, these don't exist anymore in 9.1 I don't think or perhaps they never did or I don't know where to find them.  I can't assign them to allowedUnits for some reason and they're not a part of NSDateComponentsFormatter, at least not anymore.

Comment: `.CalendarUnitMinute` et al are now `.Minute` etc. They haven't been removed.

Answer (score 2):

NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorDefault means drop leading zeros, pad other zeros for Positional units style.

e.g. with the allowedUnits values in your code, [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:120] result is "2:00" in instead of "0d 0:02:00", 
because formatter object removed all leading zero values.

If you want to reserve the zero value places, you can use NSDateComponentsFormatterZeroFormattingBehaviorNone

For why [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:12] result is 1, I think formatter object finds "12" alone is ambiguous as it has no trailing values or indicator for meaning like in "1d" for example.

Answer (score 0):

How about this function:

```
func stringFromTimeInterval(interval: NSTimeInterval) -> String {
    let ti: Int = Int(interval)
    let seconds: Int = ti % 60
    let minutes: Int = (ti / 60) % 60
    let hours: Int = (ti / 3600)
    var time: String? = nil
    if hours > 0 {
        time = String(format: "%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
    else {
        time = String(format: "%02i:%02i", minutes, seconds)
    }
    return time!
}
```

Returns time in this formatted string: 59:04 (mm:ss) or 09:01:34 (hh:mm:ss)